# Is there anything that can maximize sneak attack damage dice?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, sneak-attack

Over in Pathfinder there is this ability

> **Benefit**: A rogue with this talent gains a +4 circumstance bonus on all *Sleight of Hand* checks made to conceal a weapon. Furthermore, if she makes a *Sneak Attack* during the surprise round using a concealed weapon that her opponent didn’t know about, she does not have to roll *Sneak Attack* damage, and the *Sneak Attack* deals maximum damage. A rogue can only use the underhanded talent a number of times per day equal to her *Charisma* modifier (minimum 0).

Is there an equivalent ability in 3.5?

Comment: I reworded the title because I had guessed a different meaning for your original one. I do still have a question though: is it crucial to you that this be a feat? Suppose, say, a spell or magic item or class feature offered this, would you be interested in that?

Comment: Any method, extraordinary, supernatural, spell, feat etc.

Comment: Essentially I need a method to achieve the same or similar effect as the above quotes ability from pathfinder. If there is a raw or third party method. If not I could make a homebrew adaptation but I would prefer raw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such feat however there is a feat which allows you to reroll a stealth damage dice called Demonic Sneak Attack which might help you maximize your damage. It gives you 1 reroll for every Abyssal heritor feat you possess.

> When you make a successful sneak attack, you can reroll a number of sneak attack damage dice equal to the number of Abyssal heritor feats you possess. You must take the results of the rerolled dice.